# How to get the id of the current text in Qt c++ Combobox?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Please help. I am a beginner. This is my slot. I want the id value of the currentText(). The id column is from DepartmentTbl Table. Thank you very much

```
void addteacherform::on_newTeacherButton_clicked()
{
    dbRepository dr;
    dr.OpenDBConnection();

    //retrieve data from field
    QString fname = ui->firstnameEdit->text();
    QString mname = ui->middleIEdit->text();
    QString lname = ui->lastnameEdit->text();
    QString department = ui->DepartmentCombo->currentText(); 

    //insert query
    QSqlQuery qry1;
    qry1.prepare("INSERT INTO InstructorTbl (InsFname, InsMname, InsLname, DepartmentID)"
                "VALUES (:InsFname, :InsMname, :InsLname,:DepartmentID)");
    qry1.bindValue(":InsFname",fname);
    qry1.bindValue(":InsMname",mname);
    qry1.bindValue(":InsLname",lname);
    qry1.bindValue(":DepartmentID",department);

    if(qry1.exec()){
          QMessageBox::information(this,"Added", "Data Added Successfully");
       }
    else{
           qDebug() << "add data failed: " << qry1.lastError();
        }
     dr.CloseDBConnection();
}
```

Comment: *"I want the id value of the `currentText()`."* Do you want to extract number from string?

Comment: Please answer the first comment. It's a bit unclear exactly what you want. Or does your combobox have item data that is added to each item and you want to retrieve that?

Comment: Sorry. I mean, I want to select string from QComboBox and insert its id into database.

Comment: So, if you select 2nd items you want `id = 1`? Then `combobox->currentIndex()` seems what you want.

Comment: What if the id is custom and its from different table?

Comment: Did you a set the item data associated with each item in your combobox to its id? Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemData) you can also add this value in designer or Qt-Creator when you create your widget / form.

Comment: The combobox item data is from column DepartmentName. My problem is I need to get its id.  The id is from column departmentID. These columns are in the same table.

Comment: How are you filling this combobox?

Comment: I added `QSqlQueryModel * mCombo=new QSqlQueryModel` `qDepartment.prepare("SELECT DepartmentName FROM DepartmentTbl");` `ui->DepartmentCombo->setModel(mCombo);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `combobox->itemData(combobox->currentIndex())` for current selected text and for current selection id use `combobox->currentIndex()`

Comment: Thank you @The Acturial Kid. What if the combobox item data is from column departmentName and I want to get its id from column departmentID?

Comment: Normally you would put that in your combobox to associate the text that the user sees with the ID that is internal to the program.

Comment: Do you have the example code? I also searched about that but it seems the syntax is different.

Answer (score 1):

when combobox add item, you can use setItemData:

```
setItemData(0, "ID1", Qt::UserRole+1);
```

when itemChanged, you can get id value use itemData:

```
itemData(0, Qt::UserRole+1);
```